# Grouping texts into Buckets in R

Tags: r, text-mining, logistic-regression, text-analysis

We are working on a survey where we have a few open-ended answers part from the numeric/categorical responses.Till now we used to categorize these texts into 10-15 buckets manually so that the marketing team can take actions on it.For example, if the respondent is asked what other features he wants in a particular tablet which he is using, we will group his/hers responses into buckets like '**Better security features**', '**Better support**' etc.

Instead of doing it manually I am automating this by creating individual logistic regression/CART/Random Forest Equations for each bucket. For example for bucket one 1 use the code

```
model1=glm(Better.support~.,data=verbatimSparse,family=binomial)
verbatim$predict1=predict(model1,type="response")
```

I am building 12 other models like this and each response will be grouped into the bucket where the predicted probability is the highest.This is somewhat serving my purpose, but with the accuracy is only around 80%.Is there any other method to better classify the text.

Comment: Are you using the tm package to mine your narratives?

Comment: What did the RF produce. Have you tried Naive Bayes? How much data are you training on. What kind of text cleaning/processing are you doing? However, this question is off topic as you are asking a methodological question and not a programming question. You will likey have better luck on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the response guys.Yes i used tm package to clean and process the data.

Comment: The RF gave slightly lower accuracy than logistic regression. the output of '  RF1=randomForest(Better.support~.,data=verbatimSparse)
verbatim$predictRF1=predict(RF1) ' was values between 1 and zero and I am considering 0.5 as the threshold.

Comment: I am not so familiar with Naive Bayes unfortunately

Comment: Have you looked at the textreg package?  Also, the tidytext package is much easier to work with than TM.  How many responses are you analyzing?

Comment: I will try to use textreg package.I have around 3200 responses(test+train) .It will increase as more waves of surveys are out